# Intuition on mean curvature being equal to divergence of normal vector

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

For starters, such a thing as the divergence of the normal vector is already "counter intuitive" to me because of the definition of divergence I like using (local flux density, involving an infinitesimal volume in $\mathbb{R}^3$, whereas the normal vector is only defined on a surface)
[image: *(from wikipedia)*]
I've been introduced to the title's equality in the context of Laplace's law for pressure difference across an interface. I think I would need first an interpretation of "divergence of normal vector".

.

Comment: You're thinking of divergence and the divergence theorem for vector-valued functions of the form $\vec{F}: D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. You can think of divergence and the divergence theorem for vector-valued functions of the form $\vec{F}: D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ (functions defined over a surface of 2-space). The logic then becomes, instead of volume elements, you have flat surface elements. The divergence theorem would then state that the line integral around the flat surface (using the normal direction and not the tangent direction) = surface integral of the

Comment: divergence. What's stopping me from leaving an answer is that your surface is embedded in 3-space. $\vec{n}$ is of the form $\vec{n}:D \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. How is $\nabla$ represented? $\partial _x \hat{x} + \partial _y \hat{y}$? or $\partial _x \hat{x} + \partial _y \hat{y} + \partial _z \hat{z}$? Or something else? Also, there is ambiguity now in the divergence theorem for such surface embedded in 3-space. The vector line integral around the boundary of the surface uses what normal direction to the boundary curve?

Comment: @DWade64 in the instance we used it the normal vector only had a z-dependency in cylindrical coordinates, the teacher wrote down the whole divergence in cylindrical coordinates and radial and z-term survived. This is an engineering class so the aspects I'm talking about are just treated as details. If you give me an accessible explanation with an $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ mapping, I'll be satisfied, even if it does not directly apply to my situation.

Comment: Sorry, my train of thought doesn't apply to your problem. I was pointing out that you can still think of divergence as flux density in lower, or higher, dimensions. Instead of flux out of a unit volume, in 2-dimensions, you think of divergence as flux out of a unit surface patch (flux per unit area). You have a similar limit as the one shown in your picture, but instead of a surface integral around a volume that strinks in size, you have a line integral (using the normal direction) around a 2D patch that shrinks in size.

Comment: You can read more about this [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/greens-theorem-and-stokes-theorem/divergence-theorem-articles/a/2d-divergence-theorem). In this simpler case of a flat surface embedded in 2-dimensions, our normal vector would be something of the form $<0, 0, f(x,y)>$, in which case, I don't know how you reconcile my above comments/the link with this vector field, pointing out of the plane (any flux would be traveling out the page - making any "horizontal flux" 0). You ask a good question, and I hope someone comes along and answers it